# Remove Resize handles and border from elements with contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, contenteditable

The problem I'm having is with the contentEditable attribute in IE. (some things never change).

The problem is that I'm getting resize handles, and a thick border around `<li>` elements when they're in focus.

Any idea of how to remove them? CSS or Javascript tricks are very welcome!

Answer (score 22):

Make sure the `<li>`s don't have "layout", since elements with "layout" inside an editable element get resize handles in IE. "Layout" is a hidden property of an element in IE that is set to `true` when any one of various CSS properties are enabled:

- `position`: `absolute`
- `float` (`left` or `right`)
- `width` or `height` (any value other than `auto`)
- `min-width` or `min-height` (any value other than `none`)
- `overflow` (`hidden | scroll | auto`)
- `zoom` (any value other than normal)
- `display`: `inline-block`
- various others

Here's a link from a quick googling that explains a bit more about layout: https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-haslayout-property/

Comment: This saved my day (so far)

Comment: I cannot believe this. Thank you so much.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, including for all the other questions on resize handles with contenteditable.

Comment: that page was not found

Comment: Another life saved by this in 2020